# select items in array via checkbox form in php

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to create a form from an array and make the items selectable and be able to collect items individually for processing as variables but i get blank screen when i do echo $_POST['citem1']

```
<?php
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $data1 => $data2)
{echo
'<input type = "checkbox" name = "citem1" value = "'.$data1.'"/> ' .  
 ' price:', $data2 . "<br>";}

?>
```

What I really want to do is to be able to select one or more of the items and put them in separate variables. Help please.

```
var_dump of $_SESSION=array (size=3)
'sugar' => string '989.32' (length=6)
'lolli' => string 'inquire' (length=7)
'caramel unreal' => string '00.00' (length=5)
```

Comment: can you var_dump your $_SESSION['cart']? Please post the result of the var_dump. thanks!

Comment: done. updated question with info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of field is 'citem1', so you have to get this value with $_POST['citem1'].

To send array you have to name like 'citem1[]', and items will receive by PHP like array:

```
<?php
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $data1 => $data2)
{
echo
'<input type = "checkbox" name = "citem1[]" value = "'.$data1.'"/> ' .  
 ' price:', $data2 . "<br>";}

?>
```

Or, to send key=>value like this:

```
<?php
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $data1 => $data2)
{
echo '<input type = "checkbox" name = "'.$data1.'" value = "'.$data2.'"/> ' .  
' price:', $data2 . "<br>";
}

?>
```

But in this case you need to loop through $_POST, so a better way is:

```
<?php
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $data1 => $data2)
{
echo '<input type = "checkbox" name = "Item['.$data1.']" value = "'.$data2.'"/> ' .  
' price:', $data2 . "<br>";
}

?>
```

With name="Item[field]" you can loop through $_POST['Item'] and get key=>value.

Comment: how exactly am i gonna output the data gotten from the third suggestion you gave. Sorry, I'm not really good at this.

Comment: After send the form, in PHP you can loop with: `foreach ($_POST['Item'] as $key=>$value) { echo $key.'='.$value}`. This prints a str like: _'sugar=989.32'_. This is a example

Comment: how do i put each item in separate variables?

Comment: It depends how you wish that variables. To put again in Session, you can make like this: `foreach ($_POST['Item'] as $key=>$value) { $_SESSION['cart'][$key] = $value}`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you don't have a `data1` key in the POST vars. In the example you showed, the actual key for that checkbox is `citem1`, as that is the name (defined in the `name` attribute) of the field.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$counter = 1 ;

if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) AND !empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value){
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='citem . $counter++' value='$key'>" ;
        echo "Price : $value<br>" ;
    }
}
```

Just filter all post variables (getting all post variables is by $_POST) with a name starting with 'citem', here's how:

```
foreach($_POST as $postVar){
    if(stripos('citem') !== FALSE){
        //then it's a citem
    }
}
```